# input another set of data at update function in d3 tree using text click event

Tags: php, jquery, d3.js, hyperlink, tree

hi please visit my working jsfiddle here
               http://jsfiddle.net/elviz/Ge58Q/7/

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
  .attr("dy", 3.5)
  .attr("dx", 5.5)
  .attr("x", barWidth +20)
  .text(function(d) { return d.redirect; })
  .on("click", function(){
        var x = '{"name": "flare","children": [{"name": 2}]}';
        update(x);
   });
```

please click all the nodes and if you will see at the  node "name": "BetweennessCentrality",  it has an appended text with click function on it which it is inputting an json value for the update function to update. My question is it possible to do this way for my tree to draw the inserted json data???????  also you can check the console log to see the data objects entering the update function. I am thinking because if i click the text the console log says it has 5 data objects

Hi i got a follow up question actually this is what i want in the click event of the text

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
   .attr("dy", 3.5)
  .attr("dx", 5.5)
  .attr("x", barWidth +20)
  .text(function(d) { return d.redirect; })
  .on("click", function(d){

        if(d.redirect){
            // this is from the console log

             // its like using d.foreach get the data below
            //Object {name: 2, _children: Array[2], parent: Object, depth: 1, x: 20…}
               update(insert the data from console log);
          }



   });
```

i   actually want to loop or something to get that set of data showing in console log then input that specific set of data in update  function so it will display that specific set of tree i wish i explain my problem clearly

Comment: note: the appended text is 20pixel at the right of the rect so please scroll sir/ ma'am to see the append text which is a value of 2

Comment: follow up info its like i want to load the data where the first and second node is open.......  you can see that data in console.log but im not capable of like traversing my data to get the data that i want..........